# Passing attribute when redirecting from a filter to a JSP: Session vs Request

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, request, servlet-filters

Inside a filter I'm trying to send expired sessions back to a login page with a message that the user must login. I prefer to attach the message to the request object, rather than to the session object, so that I don't have to worry about erasing the message later.

When I use inside the filter:

```
catch (NullPointerException exc)

{

    String message = "You must log in to access this site.";
    url += "/login.jsp";
    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    httpResponse.sendRedirect(url); 
}
```

The login page does NOT display the message (message is null). However, when I use:

```
session.setAttribute("message", message);
```

The message is displayed nicely on the login page.

In servlets, I have no problem attaching and displaying messages using the request object. It's only with filters that I'm noticing this difficulty.

Why is this happening, and can it be prevented? If I must use session when redirecting from a filter, what's the best way to erase the message on the JSP side?

Answer (score 3):

Use [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) instead.

I always refer anyone asking RequestDispatcher vs SendRedirect to this article on [The Server Side](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=26425).

See also [ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29)

so you do

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, httpResponse);
```